# iCloud calendar Delete Event Request not working with caldav

Tags: icloud, icalendar, caldav

Iam using **caldav-client-v2.php** library to read calendar events from iCloud calendars,

**GetEvents()** function returns array of calendar data wich contains *ics* *url* and *etag*,which are passed to the **DoDELETERequest(href,etag)** for deleteing event,
this is working for owncloud calendar, but when i try to do this for iCloud it is not deleting the event and returns the error as '*Wrong entity tag*' the tag is something like this 
**FT=-@RU=5c162550-1ccc-4821-80d6-e2fab587c348@S=1685**

i tried passing **5c162550-1ccc-4821-80d6-e2fab587c348**  to the function, but i get the same error.
is the caldav server returns wrong etag  or how can i get it worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ETag is defined to be a quoted string, see [RFC 7232, section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3). It says:

> ```
> ETag       = entity-tag
>
> entity-tag = [ weak ] opaque-tag
> weak       = %x57.2F ; "W/", case-sensitive
> opaque-tag = DQUOTE *etagc DQUOTE
> etagc      = %x21 / %x23-7E / obs-text
>            ; VCHAR except double quotes, plus obs-text
> ```

That's also how you should have received the ETags from the server. Make sure you send the ETag exactly like you receive it. In particular, don't remove any quotes.

So try passing `"FT=-@RU=5c162550-1ccc-4821-80d6-e2fab587c348@S=1685"` instead.

Comment: Yes sir, its true, the libray was removing etag quotes with preg_replace,